# Working with both Selenium 1 and Selenium 2

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have not been able to make drag-and-drop work with Selenium 2, so I'm considering using Selenium 1 instead for drag-and-drop.

Before I dive into Selenium 1, are there known complications of having tests based on *both* Selenium 1 and Selenium 2 at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My $0.02:

Will it work?
Most likely.

Is it ideal?
Probably not.  It sounds similar to what used to be called "dependency hell"...

Most of the time, making something work takes a higher priority than making something ideal.
That being said, make sure to architect it in such a way that it's as clear as possible to the next guy *why* you are doing it, *where* and *when* it's being used and *how* it is done.